# React doesn't update on state change?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying a pretty easy thing with react, namely a display of the current browser width. It works just fine when loading the page, but it doesn't update on resizing for some reason, even though I appear to update the state... Help?

```js
import React from "react";

class SmartBr extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      WindowWidth:
        window.innerWidth ||
        document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
        document.body.clientWidth,
      WindowHeight:
        window.innerHeight ||
        document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
        document.body.clientHeight
    };
  }

  updateDimensions() {
    this.setState = {
      WindowWidth:
        window.innerWidth ||
        document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
        document.body.clientWidth,
      WindowHeight:
        window.innerHeight ||
        document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
        document.body.clientHeight
    };
  }

  /**
   * Add event listener
   */
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
  }

  /**
   * Remove event listener
   */
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    return <p>{this.state.WindowWidth}</p>;
  }
}

export default SmartBr;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) outside of the constructor is a function you call, not an object you set to it, so you need to change your `updateDimensions` function to call the [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) method, and not assign an object as you are doing now :)

```
updateDimensions() {
  this.setState({
    WindowWidth:
      window.innerWidth ||
      document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
      document.body.clientWidth,
    WindowHeight:
      window.innerHeight ||
      document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
      document.body.clientHeight
  });
}
```

Comment: What ice said. setState is a function not an object.